# Can't connect to PostGreSQL from a same-host container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am using docker to manage my Django apps, and have the same configuration on my laptop and digital ocean :

[image]

From my laptop I can connect to PostGreSQL thanks to the adminR image (https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer)

[image]

But if I try to connect to PostGreSQL from adminer on the localhost, I can't :

[image]

I can ping and find PostGreSQL from the django container :

[image]

But I can't migrate my database from django scripts :

[image]

Funny enough, I can migrate on the digital ocean cloud from my laptop :
[image]
I can see the updated database on my laptop's admineR page :
[image]

So the issue is obviously an issue of networking between the containers... But if I can ping the service, why can't django access it ????

EDIT:

1° ip route :

ip route

```
default via 167.99.80.1 dev eth0 proto static 
10.16.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.16.0.5 
10.106.0.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.106.0.2 
167.99.80.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 167.99.94.16 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-ec478ce025ee proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
```

[image]

2. iptable -S

```
  root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# apt install iptables

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

iptables is already the newest version (1.8.4-3ubuntu2).

iptables set to manually installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.

root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# iptables -S

-P INPUT DROP

-P FORWARD DROP

-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

-N DOCKER

-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1

-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2

-N DOCKER-USER

-N ufw-after-forward

-N ufw-after-input

-N ufw-after-logging-forward

-N ufw-after-logging-input

-N ufw-after-logging-output

-N ufw-after-output

-N ufw-before-forward

-N ufw-before-input

-N ufw-before-logging-forward

-N ufw-before-logging-input

-N ufw-before-logging-output

-N ufw-before-output

-N ufw-logging-allow

-N ufw-logging-deny

-N ufw-not-local

-N ufw-reject-forward

-N ufw-reject-input

-N ufw-reject-output

-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward

-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output

-N ufw-track-forward

-N ufw-track-input

-N ufw-track-output

-N ufw-user-forward

-N ufw-user-input

-N ufw-user-limit

-N ufw-user-limit-accept

-N ufw-user-logging-forward

-N ufw-user-logging-input

-N ufw-user-logging-output

-N ufw-user-output

-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input

-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input

-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input

-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input

-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input

-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input

-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER

-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER

-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -o br-ec478ce025ee -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -o br-ec478ce025ee -j DOCKER

-A FORWARD -i br-ec478ce025ee ! -o br-ec478ce025ee -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -i br-ec478ce025ee -o br-ec478ce025ee -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward

-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward

-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward

-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward

-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward

-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output

-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.5/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-ec478ce025ee ! -o br-ec478ce025ee -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-ec478ce025ee -j DROP

-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward

-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny

-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local

-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input

-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output

-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN

-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN

-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny

-A ufw-not-local -j DROP

-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP

-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-track-forward -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-track-forward -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource

-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ufw-user-limit

-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ufw-user-limit-accept

-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2375 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT

-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "

-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT

root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~#
```

3°

```
root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# docker inspect django | tail -n51
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "56733"
                    }
                ],
                "9000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "8eddd72be1915a2d0f5eb1a4812271debc4e4eca103800ede3511f3f4c56ae98",
                    
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]







root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# docker inspect nginx
[
    {
        
        "RepoTags": [
            "nginx:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2020-11-18T07:48:35.319575714Z",
        "Container": "7e8ca989e54001b9955974e36eb6d679ab4fe015066014645ef927fe88c326ec",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "7e8ca989e540",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"nginx\" \"-g\" \"daemon off;\"]"
            ],
            
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "DockerVersion": "19.03.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.19.4",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.4.4",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 132890123,
        "VirtualSize": 132890123,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
               
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
              
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]



root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# docker inspect postgreSQL
[
    {
        "Id": "c0e06b4a1fa410d0344e7b40fbc7b78308f70638affa65266357c8346570bf4e",
        "Created": "2020-11-25T11:54:28.352080019Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 437388,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-11-25T11:54:28.93246511Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        
        "ResolvConfPath":             "Name": "/postgreSQL",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/root/babymusic_django_server/postgreSql/appdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata",
                "/root/babymusic_django_server/postgreSql/my-postgres.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            
            
            
          
            
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir":                     
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "c0e06b4a1fa4",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                
                "POSTGRES_USER=romain",
                "POSTGRES_DB=baby_music",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=13",
                "PG_VERSION=13.1-1.pgdg100+1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "-c",
                "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
            ],
            "Image": "postgres:13",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGINT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "8eddd72be1915a2d0f5eb1a4812271debc4e4eca103800ede3511f3f4c56ae98",
                    
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# 



root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# docker inspect PostGresqlAdmin 
[
    {
        "Path": "entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "docker-php-entrypoint",
            "php",
            "-S",
            "[::]:8080",
            "-t",
            "/var/www/html"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 454939,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-11-25T21:00:16.349310968Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8081"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            
            
            
          
            
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "4c76998dc75a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "adminer",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
         
                           "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8081"
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "8eddd72be1915a2d0f5eb1a4812271debc4e4eca103800ede3511f3f4c56ae98",
                    
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**EDIT 2**

Check ipv4 forwarding :

```
root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Accept port forwarding :

```
root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
root@docker-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:~# iptables -S | grep FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ec478ce025ee -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-ec478ce025ee -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-ec478ce025ee ! -o br-ec478ce025ee -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-ec478ce025ee -o br-ec478ce025ee -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
```

Use 172.17.0.4 to access the database:

[image]

works !
[image]

Publishing on the --net=host gives a warning and doesn't let the access to the db :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at nmap output you can see the port is reported as filtered. That means one of these:

- The routing from Docker network (typocally 172.17. 0.0/16 ) is not setup correctly
- Each container is running it's own separate network with a overlapping subnet which prevents packets to route back correctly
- or there is a packet filter (iptables) which prevents which prevents packets to reach to the destination correctly.

What I need in addition to debug the issue, is route table (`ip route`), packet filter output (`iptables -S`), and `docker inspect` from each container.

Update:

These are the potential problems that I see:

Fix the current setup:

- You have `-P FORWARD DROP` in your iptables, this prevents the access, use: `sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` to enable that.
- Please check `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` that should be set to `1` if not edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to fix that, and reload the settings with `sysctl -p`.

OR

- Alternatively you can use postgresql ip `172.17.0.4` to access the database.
- Another option is to set postgresql network to `--net=host` and then you should be able to get around the iptables.
- Alternatively you can connect your app to postgresql network by specifying `--net=container:<postgresql_container_name>` and use `localhost` to access the database.
- You can create a separate network in docker and run all the containers there so your are able to access from anywhere to anywhere without routing through your host IP

Probably there are a few other way to achieve this, but I leave it to you to figure out :)

Update 2:

`-P INPUT DROP` is also an issue, use this for fix it: `sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

If you choose the first option for fix your current settings, make sure iptables changes are persisted otherwise you'll lose them on reboot. Consult your Linux distro manual for figure out how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It took me 20 min to update the question...

Comment: # sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding => 
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1

Comment: Ok, I also missed this one: `-P INPUT DROP`, also allow INPUT packets. (see update above)

Comment: bravo ! any idea why ocean digital would put default settings this way ?

Comment: I think it's distro dependent and nothing to do with Digital Ocean. I can see you have ufw installed, that's probably the reason. You can modify ufw settings here: `/etc/default/ufw` or completely disable it.